# Inner directive is not at all loading

Tags: angularjs

I have a outer directive and an inner directive and those two directive belongs to separate module.The outer directive is loading while inner directive is not loading the template.

my code :

**My html template**

```
 <framework>
   <ps-menu></ps-menu>          
 <framework>
```

**My directives**

```
angular.module("framework").directive("framework",function(){

  return {
    transclude:true,
    scope:{

    },
    controller:"frameworkController",
    template:"<p>Framework Content</p><div ng-transclude></div>"
  }
});


angular.module("menu",[]).directive("menu",function(){

    return {

        transclude:true,
        scope:{

        },
        controller:"menuController",
        template:"<p>Menus Content</p>",
        link:function(scope,ele,attr){

        }
    }
});
```

here the framework directive is loading but menu directive is not loaded even if I have included all those dependency in my main application module.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: You are registering directive as menu but calling as ps-menu. Please look this.

Comment: @Samir is right, and also, you're registering menu as a transclude directive but have no element in the template marked as transclude. That can cause problems too. There's also the issue that you've made each directive in its own module, but have you added both modules as dependencies to your main app module?

Comment: I made it <menu> only and I have added both module as dependency in my main app as well..still its not showing.

Comment: @Nitya, works fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/DA1lh1C78x01R1dNCcEo?p=preview